# how to setup linux bridge inside a container?

Tags: networking, bridge

I am working inside a container, trying to demonstrate linux bridge and Layer 2 connection.

I started a new container:

```
host$ docker run -it --rm --name c1 --privileged networking sh
```

On the container I used the following to create the bridge interface and tap interface

```
c1$ ip link add br0 type bridge
c1$ ip link set eth0 master br0
c1$ ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
c1$ ip link set tap0 master br0
c1$ ip link set tap0 up
c1$ ip link set br0 up
c1$ ping -I tap0 172.17.0.2
```

The last ping command is not working. 
What am I doing wrong ? is tap interface the correct one to use? 
How can I show layer 2 connection on a container with linux bridge ?

following @grawity answer, I tried the following:

```
ip link add dev veth1 type veth peer name veth2
ip link set dev veth1 up
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set veth1 master br0
ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set br0 up
ip link set veth1 up
ip link set veth2 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.3/24 dev veth1
ip addr add 10.0.0.4/24 dev veth2
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev br0


/ # brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.0242ac110002   no      veth1
                                    eth0
```

pinging to all interfaces works

```
/ # ping -c1 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms

--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.068/0.068/0.068 ms
/ # ping -c1 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms

--- 10.0.0.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.072/0.072/0.072 ms
/ # ping -c1 10.0.0.4
PING 10.0.0.4 (10.0.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms

--- 10.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.095/0.095/0.095 ms
```

both ping and arping are not working from veth2 to eth0.

```
ping -I veth2 -c1 172.17.0.2
```

ip link output

```
10: veth2@veth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether f2:8e:e4:f7:fc:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: veth1@veth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 1a:3a:26:02:8a:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: eth0@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default \    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

and ip a output

```
/ # ip -o a
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth2    inet 10.0.0.4/24 scope global veth2\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth2    inet6 fe80::f08e:e4ff:fef7:fc7c/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth1    inet 10.0.0.3/24 scope global veth1\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth1    inet6 fe80::183a:26ff:fe02:8aa1/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br0    inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global br0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br0    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: eth0    inet 172.17.0.2/16 scope global eth0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: eth0    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

tcpdump has the following

```
09:29:31.253321 ARP, Request who-has 6e2b9b27d81b (Broadcast) tell 10.0.0.4, length 28
09:29:31.253509 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.1 tell 6e2b9b27d81b, length 28
09:29:31.253541 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:be:d6:a7:81 (oui Unknown), length 28
09:29:31.253541 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:be:d6:a7:81 (oui Unknown), length 28
09:29:36.263281 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.1 tell 6e2b9b27d81b, length 28
09:29:36.263313 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:be:d6:a7:81 (oui Unknown), length 28
09:29:36.263313 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:be:d6:a7:81 (oui Unknown), length 28
09:29:36.268142 ARP, Request who-has 6e2b9b27d81b (Broadcast) tell 10.0.0.4, length 28
09:29:41.284187 ARP, Request who-has 6e2b9b27d81b (Broadcast) tell 10.0.0.4, length 28
09:29:41.284196 ARP, Request who-has 6e2b9b27d81b (Broadcast) tell 10.0.0.4, length 28
```

What am I'm missing? what is `6e2b9b27d81b` ?

Answer (score 2):

First: Your interface doesn't have an IP address configured, so you can't really send and receive IP packets through it without having an address. (`ping` uses ICMP, an IP protocol.)

Second: That's not how tap interfaces work – they won't "reflect" the `ping` packets back into the bridge; instead they expect to be connected to a *program*, e.g. OpenVPN or other VPN software.

So your approach would work if you tried, for example, to set up OpenVPN that's bridged to the host network (sharing a single subnet). But if you just want to see how Linux bridges work, you'll have better luck with `veth` interfaces.

And if all you want is a L2 connection to the outside LAN, then you're creating the bridge in the wrong place – such things are usually done on the *host*, not in a container.

---

Think of a network interface as having two ends: the 'host' end is shown in the OS and used by all software; the other end is connected to the actual network (e.g. a physical Ethernet port). If packets come in through one end, they go through the *other* end. (Bridges of course can have multiple ports, not just two, but the same general principle applies.)

When you bridge an interface, the bridge takes over the *host* side of that interface, so it only sees packets that came *from* the network. But if you use `ping -I eth0` or `ping -I tap0`, you're bypassing the bridge and sending everything towards the actual network.

```
ping ──› [eth0 ──› NIC] ──› network

ping ──› [tap0 ──› VPN software] ──› ???

               ┌─› [eth0 ──› NIC] ──› network
ping ──› br0 ──┤
               └─› [tap0 ──› VPN software] ──› ???
                     ∧
     ping -I tap0 ───┘
```

So in your situation, the tap interface is useless – all packets that you try to send through it will just get discarded, since there's no program attached to the other end. (If you check `ip link` you'll probably see it with the `NO-CARRIER` flag.)

Instead you could use, for example, a `veth` interface (the same kind that containers often use) – they are always created in pairs connected to each other. So if you tell `ping` to send packets through `veth0`, they'll loop back and come through the host side of `veth1`, where the bridge can receive them and forward through eth0 if necessary.

```
      ┌── [eth0 ──› NIC] ──› network
br0 ──┤
      └── [veth1 ‹───› veth0] ‹── ping -I veth0
```

Comment: apparently, I can't vote this as the right answer. thanks for taking the time to explain.